# How can I change the order (categories) of my bar charts in ggplot2? and flip my legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is how my data looks

```
print(genderbyage)
                Var1   Var2 Freq
1     70 and Greater Female    4
2  BETWEEN 12 AND 17 Female    1
3  BETWEEN 18 AND 23 Female    8
4  BETWEEN 24 AND 44 Female   53
5  BETWEEN 45 AND 54 Female   33
6  BETWEEN 55 AND 69 Female   28
7   BETWEEN 6 AND 11 Female    6
8        Less than 5 Female    6
9     70 and Greater   Male    4
10 BETWEEN 12 AND 17   Male    3
11 BETWEEN 18 AND 23   Male   10
12 BETWEEN 24 AND 44   Male  109
13 BETWEEN 45 AND 54   Male   56
14 BETWEEN 55 AND 69   Male   85
15  BETWEEN 6 AND 11   Male    2
16       Less than 5   Male    6
```

This is my ggplot2 code and output

```
ggplot(data = genderbyage, 
       mapping = aes(x = Var1, y = ifelse(Var2 == "Male", yes = -Freq, no = Freq), 
                     fill = Var2)) +
  geom_col(col = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = max(genderbyage$Freq) * c(-1,1),
                     breaks = seq(-150,150,by = 25)) +
  labs(y = "Population") + 
  labs(title="Age Distribution by Male & Female Genders",
       x="Age Range", 
       y="Individuals Counted",
       fill = "Gender") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

The problem is that I need the bars to be in order that ascends. So for example I need,

1. Less than 5
2. BETWEEN 6 AND 11
3. BETWEEN 12 AND 17
4. BETWEEN 18 AND 23
5. BETWEEN 24 AND 44
6. BETWEEN 45 AND 54
7. BETWEEN 55 AND 69
8. 70 and Greater

How can I rearange my bars to be in that order?

Also how can I fix my legend so that female is on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are plotted in `ggplot` in the order of their factors. You can set them manually like this:

```
ggplot(data = genderbyage, 
       mapping = aes(x = factor(Var1,
                                levels = rev(c("Less than 5",
                                               "BETWEEN 6 AND 11",
                                               "BETWEEN 12 AND 17",
                                               "BETWEEN 18 AND 23",
                                               "BETWEEN 24 AND 44",
                                               "BETWEEN 45 AND 54",
                                               "BETWEEN 55 AND 69",
                                               "70 and Greater"))) ,
                     y = ifelse(Var2 == "Male", yes = -Freq, no = Freq), 
                     fill = factor(Var2, levels = c("Male",
                                                    "Female")))) +
  geom_col(col = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = max(genderbyage$Freq) * c(-1,1),
                     breaks = seq(-150,150,by = 25)) +
  labs(y = "Population") + 
  labs(title="Age Distribution by Male & Female Genders",
       x="Age Range", 
       y="Individuals Counted",
       fill = "Gender") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the levels of the factor variables are ordered alphanumerically by default. So you need to reorder the levels. One way to do that is use `forcats::fct_relevel()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

genderbyage %>% 
  mutate(Var2 = fct_relevel(Var2, "Male", "Female"),
         Var1 = fct_relevel(Var1, "Less than 5", "BETWEEN 6 AND 11", "BETWEEN 12 AND 17", "BETWEEN 18 AND 23", 
                                  "BETWEEN 24 AND 44", "BETWEEN 45 AND 54", "BETWEEN 55 AND 69" ,"70 and Greater")) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Var1, y = ifelse(Var2 == "Male", yes = -Freq, no = Freq), 
                       fill = Var2)) +
  geom_col(col = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = max(genderbyage$Freq) * c(-1,1),
                     breaks = seq(-150,150,by = 25)) +
  labs(y = "Population") + 
  labs(title="Age Distribution by Male & Female Genders",
       x="Age Range", 
       y="Individuals Counted",
       fill = "Gender") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Comment: Honest question, as this is not the first answer I've seen with `forcats::fct_relevel()` to solve this issue. What is the benefit over `base::factor(x, levels = y)`?

Comment: For this use case: not much, other than a function name that clearly indicates what it does. For other cases, as the documentation says: "a generalisation of stats::relevel() that allows you to move any number of levels to any location".

Comment: The name of the function is not something I had considered. Thanks.